# Поломка VS Code. Полоса в интерфейсе

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code

Пишу мобильное приложение на Dart/Flutter. Использую VS Code Для редактирования кода и AAndroid Studio, чтобы иметь доступ к виртуальному телефону.
После разделения содержимого окна редактора вправо (чтобы редактировать сразу 2 файла с кодом) и возвращения к исходному режиму редактирования, в VS Code проявился баг в интерфейсе - непонятно откуда возникшая серая полоса. Позже я заметил такой же артефакт в Android Studio.

Переустановка Visual Studio не помогает. Android Studio сносить пока не пробовал.
[image: VS Code]

[image: Android Studio]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нормально. Если посчитаете, то полоса проходит в районе 80 символа - где когда то заканчивался обычный монитор. Но если знать название этой фичи - editor.rulers и погуглить, то для VSCode сразу находится ответ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code

В андроид студии жмите ctrl+shift+a и пишите ruler и там будет очевидно.

Если же это не поможет - покупайте новую видеокарту:)

Comment: Спасибо большое!
В VS Code параметр "editor.rulers": [] содержал пустой массив.
Стоило внести в него данные  - "editor.rulers": [80, 120, 160], сохранить конфигурацию, а затем удалить данные, как всё исправилось

Comment: да, просто они все на 80 выставляют (а некоторые оптимисты на 120). Но нормальные люди ставят на 78. Это просто что бы контролировать длину строк.